# Optimize Relative Error in regression problems

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression

When talking about regression problems, RMSE (Root Mean Square Error) is often used as the evaluation metric. And it is also used as the loss function in linear regression (what's more? it is equivalent to the Maximum Likelihood Method considering the distribution of the output follows a normal distribution).

In real-life problems, I find the MAPE (Mean absolute percentage error) can be more meaningful. For example, when prediction house prices, we are more interested in the relative error. Because a difference of 100k$ is not the same if the house is priced around 100k$ or 1M$.

When creating a linear regression for a house price prediction problem, I found this following graph

- x axis: real value of prices
- y axis: relative error = (prediction-real_value) / real_value

[image]

- The algorithm predicts relatively much higher prices when the real price is low
- The algorithm predicts relatively lower prices when the real price is high.

What kind of transformation can we do, in order to find a better algorithm that would have more homogeneous relative errors.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, one method of obtaining the maximum likelihood estimator is by gradient descent. In this process, the error between the predicted and actual values is determined, and the gradient of this error with respect to each of the changeable parameters of the model is found. Then, these parameters are tweaked slightly according to the calculated gradients such that the error value would be minimized. This process is repeated until the error converges to a suitably low value.

The great thing about this method is that your error or loss function has a lot of flexibility in how you define it. For instance, L2 (MSE) norm is often used, but you can also use L1 norm, smooth-L1 norm, or any other function.

An error function that yields MAPE would simply divide each error term  by the true value's magnitude, thus yeilding error relative to value size. Then, the gradients of this error can be calculated with respect to each parameter and gradient descent can be carried out as before.

Comment if there's any part of this that is unclear or needs more explanation!

Comment: Thank you Derek. Regarding the graph, what would suggest, so that the relative error can be homogeneous? I tried the log transformation of the prices, but it didn't work.

Comment: As you say in your question above, you're interested in Mean Average Percentage Error. So all you have to do is calculate the Root Mean Squared Error for each data point you use to fit the model, and then divide each calculated RMS error by the correct value (thus normalizing the errors).